# Spring optional rest endpoint path variable with multiple path variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

How can I have an optional path variable when I have multiple path variables?

This is not working: (organizationName is optional parameter)

```
  @GetMapping("/organizationreport/{month}/{year}/{organizationName}")
  public ResponseEntity<OrganizationReportJson> getOrganizationReport(
      @PathVariable("month") String month,
      @PathVariable("year") String year,
      @PathVariable Optional<String> organizationName) {
```

I get 404, wenn calling endpoint without organizationName

Answer (score 0):

Add required attribute in path variable as below.

```
@PathVariable(required = false) String organizationName
```

Comment: I have tried that also, but without success. Do I have to remove the last variable from the url as well ? `@GetMapping("/organizationreport/{month}/{year}/{organizationName}")`